# How to run Ramme with sourcecode

Tags: node.js, electron

I found an unofficial desktop application for Instagram, called [Ramme](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme).

I've installed electron for windows and downloaded the source, but couldn't run this application with that.

Should I load/install any package(s) with npm or it's not the problem?

Comment: thank you for downvote again , please help me instead !

Answer (score 3):

First enter the repository you cloned on your disk.

Then install dependencies with `npm install`

Next build the app with `npm run build`

And from now you should be able to run the application with `npm run start`

You may need to install `electron` and `gconf`(there the installation steps may vary depending on what OS are you using)